# iSCSI target volume does not show on Windows 7 iSCSI Initiator

Tags: windows-7, centos5, iscsi, disk-volume

I have a Windows VPS sitting in a DC and another Linux box sitting in another data centre. My Windows VPS (running on Windows 7 64 bit) have a small hard drive and cost a lot to upgrade, and the Linux VPS (running on CentOS 5) has a huge hard drive, so I was trying to set up a iSCSI to make the Linux VPS to run like another partition for the Windows VPS.

I set up the Linux VPS with iSCSI target just fine, using [this tutorial](http://itfixed.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-create-iscsi-target-on-centos-53.html).

Other than changing the user name and password mentioned in the tutorial and making the volume to be  a lot bigger (I used 100GB), everything else is the same.

I was able to start the Target as well:

```
/etc/init.d/iscsi-target restart
Stopping iSCSI Target:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting iSCSI Target:                                     [  OK  ]
```

The strange part comes when I was trying to set up the connection in Windows 7 using the iSCSI initiator, somehow I was able to connect to the target but there is no volume in the Volume and Devices tab list. The autoconfigure is not responding nor I could see anything in the Disk Management. I tried it on another Windows 2008 R2 VPS server (in yet another DC) and the same issue happened as well. I have also tried on my own laptop running on Windows 7 Ultimate and the same thing happened. I was following [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20121031020140/http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Connecting-Windows-7-iSCSI-SAN.html) for the Windows set up.

Could you please help?

*I have attached the screenshots here for your reference:*
[image: Target is connected]

[image: No volume??]

Comment: What is in your `/etc/initiators.allow`? Can you access the iSCSI target from the CentOS box itself? Is anything written to the logs on the CentOS box when you connect from a Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I made a typo in the configuration file and pointed the LUN to a folder that does not exist, silly me...